# Пустая выборка из MySQL, если в запросе есть параметр, содаржащий "\" или "-"

Tags: php, mysql

Вот такой запрос у меня:

```
SELECT count(art),art,art_manufacturer,group_manufacturer
FROM goods
WHERE art_manufacturer = 'ГКБ-44/150'
```

в phpMyAdmin он успешно отрабатывает и возвращает:

```
1, 950000258, ГКБ-44/150, Интерскол
```

в php скрипте у меня следующий код:

```
$art="ГКБ-44/150";\\для отладки
$query = "SELECT art,art_manufacturer,group_manufacturer FROM goods WHERE art_manufacturer = '".$art."'";
$sql = mysql_query($query);
while ($recResult = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
\\тут обработка результата
}
```

Проблема в том, что скрипт возвращает пустой результат. Где ошибка, помогите пожалуйста.

Как удалось решить мою проблему:
в полном тексте кода была такая строчка `mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");` 
после перехода на mysqli - `mysqli_query($link,"SET NAMES cp1251");`

скрипт сохранен в кодировке UTF-8.

в итоге: запрос к БД содержал такое `SELECT art,art_manufacturer,group_manufacturer FROM goods WHERE art_manufacturer ="Р“РљР‘-44/150";`
а в БД поле "art_manufacturer" выглядит так: ГКБ-44/150

Comment: а заэскейпить слеш пробовали? (то есть, просто добавить слеш перед слешем? $art="ГКБ-44\/150")

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы пользуетесь устаревшим, небезопасным и во всех отношениях наикривейшим способом работать с MySQL. Используйте mysqli или PDO с плейсхолдерами и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Спасибо, пробую mysqli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема НЕ решена.

Скорее всего, проблемы не было вовсе, либо она была в чем-то другом.

НИ "надлежащая обработка", НИ "использование mysqli" в данном случае ничем помочь не могут. Прямой слеш спецсимволом не является, и никак на запрос повлиять не может.

Скорее всего проблема была либо в кодировке, либо в банальной опечатке (отсутствии нужных данных и все такое прочее). И решилась случайно сама собой при переписывании кода.

**Примечание:**
Использовать надо было не "mysqli", a, как было сказано,  "mysqli **с плейсхолдерами.** Однако, учитывая, что mysqli с плейсхолдерами неюзабельна до такой степени, что новички в принципе не могут ее освоить, то использовать надо было в итоге **PDO с плейсхолдерами.** И продолжать использовать впредь.

Comment: "mysql_query с правильным экранированием" vs. "mysqli с плейсхолдерами" vs. "PDO с плейсхолдерами" - холивар же. Новичку важнее всего понять причину проблемы, споры о том, "как правильно готовить MySQL в PHP" здесь несколько избыточны. А причина была, скорее всего, в криво сформированном запросе, но что именно в нём было кривым - кавычки, слеши, мусорные юникодовые символы ли - по приведенной ТС информации понять невозможно.

Comment: @Shorty прав, источник проблемы был в mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");

Answer (score 0):

У Вас происходит подстановка переменной в запрос без какой-либо проверки, что находится в переменной. Если в ней есть кавычки (посмотрите, что за запрос получается, выведя `$query` в браузер), MySQL споткнётся и выдаст синтаксическую ошибку.

Вам надо [надлежаще обработать](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) переменную, прежде чем включать её в запрос.

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решена путем использования mysqli вместо mysql в качестве API работы с MySQL